# UWP: How to prevent screen lock when in full-screen mode?

Tags: uwp

I'm familiar with many docs talking about how to prevent the screen from blanking while a UWP app is active (like [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/24/how-to-prevent-screen-locks-in-your-uwp-apps/)).  And it works great in my app, except when I put my app in full-screen mode using the [ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryenterfullscreenmode) method.  When the app is full-screen, the screen will blank after so many minutes of idle time (depending on the Windows settings).  How can I prevent the screen locking/blanking while the app is in full-screen mode?

Comment: Full screen mode should not override the `DisplayRequest.RequestActive` setting. Are you sure you are calling `RequestActive`? Can you try calling it after entering full screen as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research into this, here is what I have found:

If the app has already called `DisplayRequest.RequestActive` and *then* goes into full-screen mode (calling `ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode`), then it does NOT work. (In other words, the app will not prevent sleep from happening.)

If the app has already called `DisplayRequest.RequestActive`, then goes into full-screen mode, then tries calling `DisplayRequest.RequestActive` again, it *still* does NOT work.

But, if the app has already called `DisplayRequest.RequestActive` and when it wants to go into full-screen mode calls `DisplayRequest.RequestRelease` before calling `ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode` and then calls `DisplayRequest.RequestActive` after entering full-screen mode, then it DOES work.

The same is true when exiting full-screen mode.

So, this change to Nico's code will work:

```
private bool _isRequest;
public void ActivateDisplay()
{
    //create the request instance if needed
    if (_displayRequest == null)
        _displayRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();

    //make request to put in active state
    _displayRequest.RequestActive();
    _isRequest = true;
    info.Text = _isRequest.ToString();
}

public void ReleaseDisplay()
{
    //must be same instance, so quit if it doesn't exist
    if (_displayRequest != null && _isRequest)
    {
        _displayRequest.RequestRelease();
        _isRequest = false;
        info.Text = _isRequest.ToString();
    }
    else return;
}

public void EnterFullScreen()
{
    ApplicationView applicationView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    applicationView.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal;
    bool wasRequest = _isRequest;
    if (wasRequest)
    {
        ReleaseDisplay();
    }
    applicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    if (wasRequest)
    {
        ActivateDisplay();
    }
}

public void ExitFullScreen()
{
    ApplicationView applicationView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    applicationView.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Standard;
    bool wasRequest = _isRequest;
    if (wasRequest)
    {
        ReleaseDisplay();
    }
    applicationView.ExitFullScreenMode();
    if (wasRequest)
    {
        ActivateDisplay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested `RequestActive` in full screen mode, it also work well. for ensuring that you have called `RequestActive` method you could define bool `_isRequest` to maintain `RequestActive()` gets invoked.

```
private bool _isRequest;
public void ActivateDisplay()
{
    //create the request instance if needed
    if (_displayRequest == null)
        _displayRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();

    //make request to put in active state
    _displayRequest.RequestActive();
    _isRequest = true;
    info.Text = _isRequest.ToString();
}

public void ReleaseDisplay()
{
    //must be same instance, so quit if it doesn't exist
    if (_displayRequest != null && _isRequest)
    {
        _displayRequest.RequestRelease();
        _isRequest = false;
        info.Text = _isRequest.ToString();
    }
    else return;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing, too, and it works fine when the app isn't in full-screen mode.  In your test case, are you waiting to call ActivateDisplay after going into full-screen mode?  In my case, I'm not--the app calls ActivateDisplay right at the beginning then the user can enter full-screen mode after that happens.  After I enter full-screen mode I guess the display isn't active because sleep happens, but when I exit full-screen mode it works again. (And no, ReleaseDisplay isn't getting called.)

Comment: Whether ·ActivateDisplay·  is called before or after entering full screen, it works fine in my side. could you mind share a mini sample. If you want I could post my demo to github.